# JSF - custom component, problem with expression for attribute

Tags: jsf, custom-component

I want to create custom component with attribute "title" that can have expression but I get this error:

Unable to convert string "#{myBean.text}" to class "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "title": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

Caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException - Unable to convert string "#{myBean.text}" to class "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "title": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

My classes:

```
<d:ticker title="#{myBean.text}">
    <f:verbatim>Hello JSF Custom Component</f:verbatim>
</d:ticker>

MyBean.java

public class MyBean {

    private String text = "TITLE!!!!";

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

TickerTag.java

private ValueExpression title = null;
public void setTitle(ValueExpression title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

protected void setProperties(UIComponent component) {

        super.setProperties(component);
    if (title != null) {
        if (!title.isLiteralText()) {
            component.setValueExpression("title", title);
        } else {
    component.getAttributes().put("title",title.getExpressionString());
    }
}

taglib.tld

<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>d</short-name>
    <uri>http://jsftutorials.com/</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>ticker</name>
        <tag-class>ticker.TickerTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>title</name>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and was able to solve it by including the deferred-value tag in my taglib.tld file. It's required when the component has an attribute that can be set with an EL expression. The 'type' tag is the type that the EL expression should evaluate to.

taglib.tld:

```
<tag>
  <name>CustomComponent</name>
  <tag-class>com.test.components.CustomComponent</tag-class>
  <attribute> 
     <name>someAttribute</name> 
     <description>The custom attribute</description>
     <deferred-value>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
     </deferred-value>
  </attribute> 
</tag>
```

Comment: It is showing error for `<deferred-value>`. the *doctype* I used is `<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">`